# jQueryMobile on one page of a Phonegap app

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an app that I am developing with phonegap and want to use jQueryMobile for just one page of the app.  I am also using Iscroll.  The issue is that when I load the one page that jQueryMobile is used on everything continues to work fine.  But when navigating to another page.  The iscroll no longer works.

Is there a way to stop the script from the jQueyMobile from continuing when the user leaves that page?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without knowing the specifics of your code/app, but try adding the following attribute to the links on your jQuery Mobile page.

```
data-ajax="false"
```

You might be bringing the new pages into the existing DOM, which will retain existing behaviour.